# Break text at span using CSS class

Tags: html, css

I have a website I am developing locally and I need to break the text at a certain point.

I don't want to use the `<br />` code (someone told me it is considered bad HTML) so I want to find a way to do it with a span class.

For example:

`<p> Text Here. I want a break <span class="break">here</span> </p>` and it would break after the word within the span.

Is there a way to do this, or a is using the br tag *not* bad HTML (if so, I will just use that; but I still would like to know if its possible in CSS.)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `<br />`. Your "someone" is wrong.

Comment: Making span display as block should put it on the line below

Comment: @onetrickpony How would I do this?

Comment: @j08691 Thank, though I still would like to know if I can do it in CSS.

Comment: I will never understand why using an extra span and couple of lines of CSS is somehow better then `<br>`...

Comment: @Tigran: one reason is that you may decide later to display it inline and changing the html markup is usually harder than changing the css code

Comment: @onetrickpony I often find changing the HTML to be easier, as to change the CSS you have to ensure that that selector doesn't happen to also influence something else on the page

Comment: @TigranPetrossian and RPiAwesomeness:  I have the feeling that the "someone" in the question was actually referring to setting `width: 100px` or whatever, and that line breaks should be automatically chosen by the browser, not explicitly put in the HTML or the CSS.  You can never tell beforehand when a user has text zoom on, or a small window, or whatever else that'll cause these explicit line breaks to wrap early and create a staggered form where every other line is half the available width.  It's horrible and difficult to read when that happens.

Comment: @Izkata Yes, that is probably what he was referring to. Thanks to all -who-participated in answering this question. It solved my problem and a little more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong at all with using the break tag (`<br />`). However, if you feel the need to use CSS, try:

```
.break {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vwm5e/)**

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Will mark as answer as soon as I can.